# Настройка static ip на ubuntu server в virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Добрый день, появилась проблема по настройке сети в ubuntu server на vm.

- Установил Ubuntu Server 16.04
- Настроил Apache2, PHP, MySQL и другие службы успешно
- В настройках Вирт Машины поставил соединение типа Bridge
- В файле /etc/network/inferfaces стоит auto inet dhcp
- Могу успешно подсоединяться к машине через ssh используя IP адрес, а так же работает сервер когда обращаюсь из браузера к странице

И здесь появилась необходимость задать домен для ip в файле hosts, а так же настроить подключение по ssh ,без требования вводить пароль.

- Задал в файле /etc/network/inferfaces static ip

В итоге все смог настроить что хотел, домен и ssh работает на ура. Но дело в том, что я часто перемещаюсь с ноутбуком, и при использовании интернета в другом месте, у меня ложится Apache2 не говоря уже об подключении по ssh.
И приходится менять static ip чтобы все снова заработало.

Использовал раньше vagrant, но отказался от него из-за того, что в некоторых проектах еще есть старые PHP версии, не говоря уже о том что они часто разные(конфигурации сервера). Это если использовал Vagrant глобально на машине. На каждый проект делать новый vagrant откровенно говоря мне не понравилось, мне легче сделать копию vdi и уже в системе менять мелкие настройки сервера(это занимает меньше времени и тело движений).

В Vagrant понравилось что по умолчанию там чтоит 192.168.10.10 к которому и идет всегда подключение, и с разных мест где бы я не был заходит по этому адресу на ура. Скажите пожалуйста, как я могу настроить Вирт машину таким же образом, чтобы прописать статический ip на свое усмотрение, и всегда обращаться к нему из разных мест? Как я понял, Host-only может дать такую возможность, но он обрубает в вирт машине доступ в сеть и оставляет только локальную.

Буду очень признателен за помощь, так как уже второй день бьюсь над проблемой и никак не прихожу к решению.
P.S. Использую OSX(Macbook pro), вдруг это важно

Comment: Вагрант по дефолту ставит режим сети в  NAT и пробрасывает порт SSH на localhost:2222. Это довольно удобно и для вручную созданных машин.

Comment: А вы можете более подробно описать что необходимо сделать, либо дать ссылку на какой-либо источник?

Comment: Да просто в настройках сети вертуальной машины. Там и тип сети выбирается и проброс портов.

Comment: Пробую, ругается 403 ошибкой и не пускает по 22 порту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге решилось это дело пробросом портов как предложил в комментариях Владимир. Правда надо было еще добавить Host-only адаптер. Если кому интересно могу кинуть скрины настроек

Answer (score 1):

В MacOS есть служба `Bonjour`, которая реализует протокол `Zeroconf`. У линукса тоже есть реализация этого протокола, но называется `Avahi` (пакет `avahi-daemon`). Собсно делай сеть через `dhcp`, авторизацию `ssh` через ключ, а к виртуалке подрубайся по `содержимое-файла-/etc/hostname-точка-local`. Т.е. для хостнейма `ubuntu-serv` пиши `ssh ubuntu-serv.local`. Ну и с браузером та же фигня.